# Are there ways set a local variable of a function inside stream java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to java 8 and exploring different possibilities with it .I have a block of code that looks like this

```
String latestDeliveryAddress = "";
List<String> deliveryAddresses = 
            compositeEvent.getData().getShopperProfiles().getDeliveryAddressIDs();
List<Addresses> addresses = 
            compositeEvent.getData().getPersons().getContactInfo().getAddresses();
for(String deliveryAddress : deliveryAddresses){
    for(Addresses address : addresses) {
        if(deliveryAddress.equalsIgnoreCase(address.getId())){
            if(address.getModified().compareTo(latestDeliveryAddress)>0){
                latestDeliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if its even possible to do this using java stream and lambda expressions?

I can get to point where I can find the address but can't find a way to set local variable with it

```
Stream<String> stringStream = deliveryAddresses.stream().filter({
                    deliveryAddress -> addresses.stream().anyMatch(address -> address.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(deliveryAddress))
```

I am now trying to do this

```
 Map<String,String> dates =
                    deliveryAddresses.stream()
                            .filter (
                                    deliveryAddress -> addresses.stream()
                                            .allMatch(address -> address.getId().equals(deliveryAddress)))
                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(addresses.get(0).getId(),addresses.get(0).getModified()));
```

but to Map method is throwing an error .

My final solution is this. It works but please let me know if there is a better way to do this

```
final String[] latestDeliveryAddress = {""};  
deliveryAddresses.stream().forEach (
                                        deliveryAddress -> addresses.stream().forEach(addresses1 -> 
                                        {
                                            if(addresses1.getId().equals(deliveryAddress)){
                                                if(addresses1.getModified().compareTo(deliveryAddress)<0){
                                                    latestDeliveryAddress[0] = addresses1.getId();
                                                }
                                                    
                                            }
                                        })
                                      );
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: But you should try first

Comment: What would be your sample input and expectation from the original code?

Comment: @Naman want to set the varaiable latestDeliveryAddress with the delivery address that has been modified most recently

Comment: Why not `String latestDeliveryAddress = stringStream.findFirst().orElse("");` ?

Comment: @Eklavya bcuz there are multiple address not not just one

Comment: @AmanKumarSinha But in your current code you just set one, right?

Comment: No the if condition checks whether the date being iterated is more recent or not. If yes then update the variable. The variable is one but the possible candidates r multiple

Comment: `address.getModified().compareTo(latestDeliveryAddress)>0` here what is `address.getModified()` return ?

Comment: a date in String format

Comment: latestDeliveryAddress may be some id, I don't understand then meaning of `address.getModified().compareTo(latestDeliveryAddress)>0` this comparison ?  May be you want latest address by  address.getModified()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223046/discussion-between-aman-kumar-sinha-and-eklavya).

Comment: Your loop compares the result of `getModified()` with the same string you’re comparing with the result of `getId()`. That looks suspicuos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s generally recommend to study [the Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#method.summary) and all of its operations. `forEach` should be the last resort or, well, if you try to rewrite a loop solution and only find `forEach` suitable, it may be a sign that it’s better to stay with the loop.

You can use

```java
List<String> deliveryAddresses =
    compositeEvent.getData().getShopperProfiles().getDeliveryAddressIDs();
List<Addresses> addresses =
    compositeEvent.getData().getPersons().getContactInfo().getAddresses();

String latestDeliveryAddress = addresses.stream()
    .filter(a -> deliveryAddresses.contains(a.getId()))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Addresses::getModified))
    .map(Addresses::getId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no matching address"));
```

If you truly want to match IDs case insensitive, you may use

```java
Set<String> deliveryAddresses = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
deliveryAddresses.addAll(
    compositeEvent.getData().getShopperProfiles().getDeliveryAddressIDs());
List<Addresses> addresses =
    compositeEvent.getData().getPersons().getContactInfo().getAddresses();

String latestDeliveryAddress = addresses.stream()
    .filter(a -> deliveryAddresses.contains(a.getId()))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Addresses::getModified))
    .map(Addresses::getId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("no matching address"));
```

Generally, it’s recommended to use a `Set` for `deliveryAddresses` if the size can get large. For case sensitive matches, you can use a `HashSet`, which will provide an even faster lookup.

Though, it’s strange that you have to perform such match operation of two collections at this place. Whatever `compositeEvent.getData()` returns, should provide an API to get only the applicable addresses in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, however I am using a class attribute instead of a local variable inside a method:

```
private String variable;

void testStream() {
    List<String> elements = List.of("Fire", "Wind", "Rain");
    elements.stream().anyMatch(element -> {
        variable = element; 
        return element.startsWith("Ra");    
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it works but the variable must be final . In my case I have to update the variable whenever I encounter a newer modified date

Comment: If you use a class variable/attribute, it must be NOT final. (I declared it outside the method)

Comment: `String result = elements.stream() .filter(element -> element.startsWith("Ra")) .findFirst() .orElse(fallback);`

Comment: Based on how the question developed, I would do it also as @Holger suggested